# Adding a NSMenu to a NSTableCellView which pops up on right click

Tags: swift, nstableview, nsmenu, nsmenuitem, nstablecellview

I want to popup a `NSMenu` when the user right-clicks on a `NSTableCellView` within a `NSTableView`.

```
let cell = myTableView.make(withIdentifier: "myCustomTableCellView", owner: self) as! MyTableCellView // subclass of NSTableCellView

let menu = NSMenu()
menu.autoenablesItems = false
menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Test", action: nil, keyEquivalent: ""))

cell.menu = menu
```

But the menu pops not up if the user clicks on the cell.

I couldn’t find any `sendActionOn` methods or something similar.

Would be great if someone could help!

Answer (score 8):

No need to do anything fancy. You can design your menu in Interface Builder.

1. Drag a `Menu` from the Object Library to your View Controller
2. Ctrl-drag from the `Table View` to this menu and connect it to the `menu` outlet

[image: Connect Table View to Menu]

3. Connect the menu items with `IBActions` in your `View Controller`:

Say you have 3 actions on your right-click menu

```
@IBAction func menuAction1(_ sender: Any) {
    print("You clicked Item 1 for row \(self.tableView.selectedRow)")
}

@IBAction func menuAction2(_ sender: Any) {
    print("You clicked Item 2 for row \(self.tableView.selectedRow)")
}

@IBAction func menuAction3(_ sender: Any) {
    print("You clicked Item 3 for row \(self.tableView.selectedRow)")
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It basically works, but this way every type of TableCellView within the TableView has that menu. My question was how to  add a NSMenu (programatically) to a specific TableCellView?

Comment: While this works at showing the menu, right-click doesn't trigger row selection on the tableview, so `self.tableView.selectedRow` is always going to be `-1`, unless the row is preselected by normal (left) click first.

Comment: Should use `self.tableView.clickedRow` to get the clicked row.